# Asp.net Razor Page Vs MVC, How to sperate the view model out of the PageModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

Mine Previous Projects all in MVC 5 or ASP.net Core MVC, Just wonder if switch to Razor Pages, how can I separate out the models to store in other project? All the while mine view models which bind to views is from Project.Models project which share across Business layer, ASP.net Core MVC and Web API. But now the Razor Page are directly write model and controller behind class files. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would not be able to just put the models in a separate project, and reference the project in your Razor Pages project? Are you following some tutorial that does it all in the same project?

Comment: @mortb, I study few articles, all is code the property and Bind Property behind the PageModel. But the model need to be separate from presentation layer so that business layer and web API also can refer to it.

Comment: This link seems to describe what you want: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/asp-net-core-simpler-asp-net-mvc-apps-with-razor-pages#architectural-pattern read paragraph "architectural pattern" and "migrating". In the end it says "You should be able to reverse these steps to move from a Razor Pages implementation to a Controller/View-based approach, in most cases. Following these steps should work for most simple MVC-based actions and views. More complex applications may require additional steps and troubleshooting." which seems to be what you want to do

Comment: @mortb thank for the sharing link, I think got 1 solution is the view model still in different project, than BindProperty is refer to the view model than the PageModel itself. Thank a lot. Maybe currently will still using MVC, and do small project to test Razor Page since the Blazor is same pattern to Razor Page.